# Subnav "active" when it shouldn't be

Tags: html, css

http://wilwaldon.com/itsbroken/templateleftnav.php

As you can see on the left navigation the link for Template 01 is highlighted green. The link underneath is also highlighted green.

I think the problem lies with the initial LI controlling the ul underneath somehow.

I need to keep the xhtml formatted exactly how it is right now and only change the CSS to fix this problem.

I'd appreciate any help you may be able to point me in the right direction, I'm pretty stuck at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green background for the highlighted `li` element goes for the entire element, including the nested `ul`.  To get around it, override the text and background color of the nested `ul` like this:

```
li.leftactive ul {
    background-color: #E3DECA;
}

li.leftnav1b a {
    color: #363;
}
```

You might want to tweak margins and/or padding as well, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you Par. It's always the little things that get me! You've been check marked :) Now if I can only get the link color to change I'll be all good. Definitely on my way though, thank you!

Comment: I made a small addition to my answer that should take care of the link color too.

Comment: Tried that and it's still white. I'll mess around with it for a bit and see what I can come up with. Thanks again!